# Prometheus Grafana create Latency Distribution Graph

Tags: prometheus, grafana

how to make to make latency distribution on grafana based on prometheus query?

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From Grafana 8, you have a new visualization type : [**Histogram**](https://grafana.com/docs/grafana/latest/visualizations/histogram/).

Otherwise, if you'r not on Grafana 8, you have to add a query for each quantile on your Graph panel.